# Linked list implementation as an exercise

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've only ever written C++98 code, because that's what I learned and at work we are limited to C++98 due to the fact that we sell source code to customers who are reluctant to upgrade their toolchains.

Therefore, I decided to learn modern C++ in my own time. As a first exercise I decided to implement a linked list using as many modern features of C++ that I'm aware of. The code passes my unit tests and valgrind says I have no memory leaks, but I would like a review of my code, because I would like to know if I wrote "good" modern C++.

I would really appreciate if someone could please review the code:

```
#include <memory>

using std::shared_ptr;

namespace ds {

        class NullNextException : public std::exception { };

        template <class T>
        class Node {

        public:
                Node(T _value, shared_ptr< Node<T> > _next = nullptr) noexcept :
                        value(_value),
                        next(_next) {

                }

                Node(const Node<T> &) = delete;
                Node<T> &operator = (const Node<T> &) = delete;

                const T &get() const noexcept {
                        return value;
                }

                const Node<T> &get_next() const {
                        if (next == nullptr) {
                                throw NullNextException();
                        }
                        return *next;
                }

                const shared_ptr< Node<T> > &get_next_ptr() const noexcept {
                        return next;
                }

                bool end() const noexcept {
                        return (next == nullptr);
                }

                void set(T &_value) noexcept {
                        value = _value;
                }

                void set_next(shared_ptr< Node<T> > _next) noexcept {
                        next = _next;
                }

        private:
                T value;
                shared_ptr< Node<T> > next;
        };

        class EmptyListException : public std::exception { };
        class OutOfBoundsException : public std::exception { };

        template <class T>
        class List {

        public:
                List() noexcept :
                        front(nullptr),
                        n_nodes(0) {

                }

                List(const List<T> &) = delete;
                List<T> &operator = (const List<T> &) = delete;

                void insert_front(T &value) {
                        auto node = shared_ptr< Node<T> >(new Node<T>(value, front));
                        front = std::move(node);
                        n_nodes++;
                }

                void insert_back(T &value) {
                        if (front == nullptr) {
                                insert_front(value);
                                return;
                        }

                        auto node = shared_ptr< Node<T> >(new Node<T>(value));
                        auto back = front;
                        while (!back->end()) {
                                back = back->get_next_ptr();
                        }
                        back->set_next(node);
                        n_nodes++;
                }

                T pop_front() {
                        if (front == nullptr) {
                                throw EmptyListException();
                        }

                        T retval = std::move(front->get());
                        front = std::move(front->get_next_ptr());
                        n_nodes--;
                        return std::move(retval);
                }

                T pop_back() {
                        if (front == nullptr) {
                                throw EmptyListException();
                        }

                        auto penult = front;
                        auto back = front;
                        if (!back->end()) {
                                back = back->get_next_ptr();
                        }

                        while (!back->end()) {
                                penult = back;
                                back = back->get_next_ptr();
                        }

                        T retval = std::move(back->get());

                        if (back == front) {
                                front = nullptr;
                        }
                        else {
                                penult->set_next(nullptr);
                        }

                        n_nodes--;
                        return std::move(retval);
                }

                const T &nth(size_t n) const {
                        if (n >= size()) {
                                throw OutOfBoundsException();
                        }

                        auto ith = front;
                        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < n; ++ii) {
                                ith = ith->get_next_ptr();
                        }
                        return ith->get();
                }

                size_t size() const noexcept {
                        return n_nodes;
                }

        private:
                shared_ptr< Node<T> > front;

                size_t n_nodes;
        };

}
```

Comment: Let me just say "thank you!" for using valgrind and running unit tests **before** posting code here.  I wish everyone did!

Answer (score 2):

Before I write anything about your code, let me just say I find your interest in sharpening your skills commendable. Now on to the review!

#### Encapsulation

Your `Node` class template is an implementation detail, is it not? So placing it in the `ds` namespace where the public interface of the linked list is supposed to be is a break in encapsulation. I would suggest to either move it into `List`, or into a `detail` namespace if you intend to reuse it.

```
namespace ds {
  namespace detail {
    template <class T> class Node {/* As before /*};
  }
}
```

This is a common idiom for isolating implementation details from user code. And even though it's not an access specifier like `private`, it sends a clear message that *this should not be touched or used for risk of nasal demons<sup>TM</sup>*. I call it the responsible adult approach. And it works quite well in libraries like boost.

#### Identifiers

The identifier `ds` is kinda lackluster. What does it mean? You should give namespaces long and meaningful names. They are there to avoid collisions. If a client wants to shorten it. They can use a namespace alias.

#### Namesapce Pollution

You have a using declaration at global scope in a header. While it isn't as bad as a using directive, it's still namespace pollution. You shouldn't introduce identifiers into the global namespace of clients. Especially those that are implementation details. Either move it into one of *your* namespaces (`detail` comes to mind). Or write `std::shared_ptr` (honestly, it's not that much to type).

#### Unnecessary Overhead

Speaking of `std::shared_ptr`. Why are you using it? Do you expect a node to be under shared ownership? I would say not, so why pull in the overhead of keeping a track of sharing.

A node will always have a unique owner. And there's another smart pointer in the standard library to model just that, the aptly named [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). Best part is, that it's likely to have no overhead compared to a raw pointer.

#### `noexcept` correctness

You mark certain things as `noexcept`, such as the node c'tor, for instance. But are you sure this isn't lying to the compiler? There's a template parameter there (`T`), and you copy construct it. It may throw, that isn't unheard of. A class like `std::vector` may throw while copying. So you shouldn't just assume it's `noexecpt`. Instead, make the specification depend on the specification that is given to `T`'s copy c'tor. Use the [`noexcept` *operator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept):

```
Node(T _value, shared_ptr< Node<T> > _next = nullptr) noexcept(noexcept(T(_value)))
```

#### Const correctness

You insert copies of `T` into the list, and that's fine. But by this very virtue, you aren't modifying the parameter you are given. So it should be a reference to constant object.

```
insert_front(T const &value)
```

#### Use of `auto`

Nothing much to say here. You use it judiciously and I think that should at least be mentioned. :)